# AngularJs working with nested arrays within objects

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display information from child and parent data within a json object. Below is my data:

```
$scope.electionDetails = {
  id : 1,
  election_type: "CityCouncil",
  election_name: "City A City Council Elections
  candidates : [{
               id: 1,
               election_id: 1,
               position_id: 1,
               first_name: "John",
               last_name: "Doe"
               },
               {
               id:2,
               election_id:1,
               position_id:1,
               first_name: "Jane",
               last_name: "Doe"
               },
               {
               id:3,
               election_id:1,
               position_id:2,
               first_name: "Mike",
               last_name: "Doe" 
               },
               {
               id:4,
               election_id:1,
               position_id:2,
               first_name: "Mary",
               last_name: "Doe"
               }],
 positions : [{
             id:1,
             election_id: 1,
             position: "Seat 1"
             },
             {
             id:2,
             election_id:1,
             position: "Seat 2"
             }]

}
```

I want to display this data grouped, using angular like so:

**City A City Council Elections**

Seat 1

- John Doe
- Jane Doe

Seat 2

- Mike Doe
- Mary Doe

Comment: Use table with ng-repeat

Comment: What is your question?  Have you made an attempt to display the data? If so, can you post it here?

Comment: I haven't attempted. I know how to use ng-repeat just not in a way that will group this data correctly.

Comment: I have a solution for you. It is also worth noting that you are missing an ending " and , at the end of the "election_name" property in your code you have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The HTML structure may not be exactly what you want, so you can change up what tags you use, but this is the basic idea using `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` to create lists of candidates for a given seat.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/paxeguwodu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is correct.  You can also use the 'filter' filter, instead of ng-if https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Agreed. If it were my application I would use filter, I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible for the OP. Great suggestion, though!

Comment: Thanks! I think I could I apply this with a filter now.